# jQuery ajax request proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, proxy

How I can do the following operation with jQuery:

1. Some library send ajax request via
   $.ajax
2. I need to catch all these
   requests, and in some cases abort
   them, and instead pass off another
   data.

I found, that in `jQuery 1.5` there were introduced new methods, such as `ajaxPrefilter` and `ajaxTransport`. I also tried `ajaxSetup` with `beforeSend`,
but I can't achieve 2 points of these working...

Comment: Do you need to catch the request or the response? surely if you need to catch the request you would just put an if statement around the $.ajax and not make the request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this issue was fixed in jQuery 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use this unless until you are damn sure about what you are doing**

I am not sure about the ajax intercepter libraries. But i can tell you the nasty hack

- Take copy of your original jquery ajax instance

  ```
        var oldAjaxInstance; //some global variable
        oldAjaxInstance = $.ajax;  //in document load
  ```
- And assign your intercepert method to the $.ajax pointer

  ```
        $.ajax = myAjaxwrapper;
  ```

myAjaxwrapper looks womething like this

```
function myAjaxwrapper(a) {
     //your logic to change the request data's
     if (you are ok to allow the ajax call) {
         //re Assgin the actual instance of jquery ajax
         $.ajax =oldAjaxInstance;           
         //and call the method
         $.ajax(a);
     }
     //Otherwise it wont be called
}
```

- And onsucess of your ajax call reassign your ajax wrapper to jquery ajax

  ```
             oldAjaxInstance = $.ajax;  
             $.ajax = myAjaxwrapper;
  ```

Comment: Common issue in your answer, is that I can't access $.ajax... In could fire any library. I have to catch it outside...

Comment: @Alex, you are right... thats why i warned you at the beginning itself... :(

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but it works only in couple with two methods :)

```
function enableFakeAjax(isEnable, fakeData) {
  isFakeAjax = isEnable;

  $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (isFakeAjax) {
      jqXHR.abort();

      originalOptions.success(fakeData);
    }
  });

  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
      if (isFakeAjax) {
        jqXHR.abort();
      }
    }
  });
}


enableFakeAjax(true, jsonData);
isFakeAjax = false;
```